# Set EntityCollection in a Linq projection

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I would like to know how I can set an EntityCollection in a Linq Projection.
Below is my code:

```
var orders = (from order in context.Orders
   select new
   {
    reference = order.reference,
    pe = order.OrderExecutions //this is an EntityCollection
   })
.AsEnumerable()
.Select(o =>
     (Orders)new Orders
     {
      reference = o.reference,
      OrderExecutions = o.pe
     }
).ToList().AsQueryable();
```

(This code seems weird but it needs to be like this in order to work in a telerik grid)

The instruction `OrderExecutions = o.pe` involves this error:

> The EntityCollection has already been
>   initialized. The
>   InitializeRelatedCollection method
>   should only be called to initialize a
>   new EntityCollection during
>   deserialization of an object graph.

OrderExecutions is an EntityCollection contained in the object Orders.

How can I avoid this error? Any idea?

Should I modify the generated code in the Order object?

```
[XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
[SoapIgnoreAttribute()]
[DataMemberAttribute()]
[EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("PModel", "FK__orderExec__refer__70DDC3D8", "OrderExecutions")]
public EntityCollection<OrderExecutions> OrderExecutions
{
 get
 {
  return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedCollection<OrderExecutions>("PModel.FK__orderExec__refer__70DDC3D8", "OrderExecutions");
 }
 set
 {
  if ((value != null))
  {
   ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.InitializeRelatedCollection<OrderExecutions>("PModel.FK__orderExec__refer__70DDC3D8", "OrderExecutions", value);
  }
 }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

The query should be re-written as

```
var orders = from order in context.Orders
             select new
             {
                 reference = order.reference,
                 OrderExecutions = order.OrderExecutions //this is an EntityCollection
              };
```

There is no need to convert to IEnumerable and then re-select the same fields. And then there is no need to convert to a List, then back to an IQueryable, because a LINQ query naturally returns an IQueryable object. By calling ToList() the query *is executed against the data source*. It's almost always better to defer those calls until after any additional restrictions have been put into place.